# Using expression from ng-repeat inside an ng-include

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-include

I may have worded this title incorrectly but I am hoping to still get some help.  I am trying to use an expression that I get from an ng-repeat to include an new page using ng-include but it is not rendering.  I can write in the page I want, but I want to use the expression to include multiple pages dynamically

```
<div ng-app="" id="container" ng-controller="pagesController">
<span ng-repeat="x in pages">
   <a href="{{x.HTML}}" target="_self">{{x.Page | uppercase}}</a>
   <b ng-if="!$last" href="#"> - </b>
   <div ng-include="'{{x.HTML}}'" name="{{x.Page}}"></div>
</span>
```

But if I manually enter the pages like so:

```
<div ng-include="'generic.htm'" name="generic"></div>
```

It works as expected.

I am getting used to Angular.js obviously and I am not sure if this is possible or if I can do what I want really.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your ng-include is wrong <div ng-include src="'views/sidepanel.html'"></div>

Comment: Thank you very much.  Still learning this stuff and it all helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-include` is an angular directive, and assuming `x.HTML` is a string, omit the `{{}}` and the single quotes:

```
ng-include="x.HTML"
```